# Sequential operations in pyspark dataframes

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a question about the best way to deal with dataframe (df) transformations. Let's suppose that I have a main df and I need to join this df with other 3 dfs. Which one below is the best way (better performance) to achieve this? Create several dfs or reassign to existing one?

1 - One dataframe for each step

```
df = spark.read.orc(file)
df2 = spark.read.orc(file2)
df3 = spark.read.orc(file3)
df4 = spark.read.orc(file4)

df5 = df.join(df2, df.col==df2.col, 'inner')
df6 = df5.join(df3, df5.col==df3.col, 'inner')
df7 = df6.join(df4, df6.col==df4.col, 'inner')

df7.write.orc(file)
```

2 - Reassign to existing one

```
df = spark.read.orc(file)
df2 = spark.read.orc(file2)
df3 = spark.read.orc(file3)
df4 = spark.read.orc(file4)

df = df.join(df2, df.col==df2.col, 'inner')
df = df.join(df3, df.col==df3.col, 'inner')
df = df.join(df4, df.col==df4.col, 'inner')

df.write.orc(file)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of points to note down first:

> *`DataFrame` is `immutable`, any transformation on it will create a new `DataFrame`*.
>
> *All transformations in Spark are `lazy`*.

So assigning or reassigning the transformed `Dataframe` to a variable doesn't make any difference in terms of `query execution plan`.

So when you finally materialize the resultant `DataFrame` (`.write` in this case), Spark will create (and optimize) single query plan with all 4 joins in it.
So it doesn't really matter** how you go about writing the transformation.

**But yes there are few things you can consider if you know your data well and think an inner join will drop number of records significantly, then maybe you can perform that join before other inner joins.

Answer (score 0):

The second one. Spark's DAG is intelligent enough to detect joins.

Even better, inside the second approach, instead of assigning `df` multiple times, you could just do:

```
df = df.join(df2, df.col==df2.col, 'inner')
    .join(df3, df.col==df3.col, 'inner')
    .join(df4, df.col==df4.col, 'inner')
```